# Seeking improvements for this database design

Tags: sqlite

I have a database design that works, but is probably very inefficient. I'd welcome suggestions about how to make it more efficient, whether it's redesigning the tables or views, or adding indexes. My SQL skills are mediocre, so I'm seeking guidance.

Back story: I'm developing a database that represents objects and their relationships with each other. It has two tables. "objects" holds data about objects, such as hashes, strings, numbers, etc. "relationships" establishes the relationships between hashes and other objects.

The "fclass" field requires some explanation. fclass represents the class of the object. In this example, the only two values are 'h' for hash and 's' for scalar (a string, number, boolean, or null). fclass might have many other values that represent derivatives of hash, such as 'person' or 'product'.

One requirement is the ability to query for hashes that have a certain fclass and contain certain key/value pairs. My current strategy is to create a view that lists each key/value pair along with its parent element and the parent's fclass. Here's the design for the database.

```
-- objects
create table objects (
    pk varchar(36) primary key,
    fclass text not null, -- type of object: h=hash, s=scalar, but might be others
    scalar text -- the value of a scalar object
);

-- insert a hash and a scalar
insert into objects(pk, fclass) values('a', 'h');
insert into objects(pk, fclass, scalar) values('b', 's', 'fred@example.com');

-- relationships
create table relationships (
    pk varchar(36) primary key,
    parent varchar(36) not null references objects(pk) on delete cascade,
    child varchar(36) not null references objects(pk) on delete cascade,
    hkey varchar(255)
);

-- set a scalar as an element for a hash
insert into relationships(pk, parent, child, hkey) values('c', 'a', 'b', 'email');

-- view of key/value pairs
create view hash_pairs as
    select r.parent, r.child, r.hkey, c.scalar
    from objects c, relationships r
    where (c.pk = r.child) and (r.hkey is not null);

-- view of parent elements with the parent fclasses
create view hash_values as
    select hp.parent, p.fclass, hp.child, hp.hkey, hp.scalar
    from hash_pairs hp, objects p
    where (hp.parent = p.pk);

select * from hash_values;
```

Selecting from hash_values produces output like this:

```
parent      fclass      child       hkey        scalar          
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------------
a           h           b           email       fred@example.com
```

That's the output I want. I just want to get to it more efficiently. Any suggestions on how to improve performance?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a relational database inside your relational database.  Is there some reason you need everything in the same 2 tables instead of having tables for different types of objects?

Comment: I'm developing a nosql database called "Fiona". I think it will be very cool. Yes, I know there are quite a few other nosql databases out there. For now, just humor me. I need to make that view more efficient to support what might be millions of records.